# Android Runtime exception : An error occur while executing doinbackground

Tags: android, xml-parsing, runtimeexception, xmlpullparser

I am parsing online Xml using XmlPullParserFactory and showing the details in a listview. I have put the condition for checking internet, but sometimes it takes time to fetch data and crashes.The code which I am using is below.

```
      private void runningABackProcess() {
      Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
      Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {                        
      public void run() {
       try{
             //Thread.sleep(5000);

         new DoSomeTask().execute();                           

                  }catch(Exception e){}
                           // myPd_ring.dismiss();
              }
           };
           mHandler.post(myRunnable);

    }
         private class DoSomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
     {


        @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        try { 
         isInternetPresent = icd.isConnectingToInternet
         if(isInternetPresent){                             
              URL url = new     URL("njhgjghjkjhkjl");                                 
              XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();  
              XmlPullParser xpp=factory.newPullParser();      
              xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");                                   
              int eventType=xpp.getEventType(); 
              if(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                  {
            if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)     
                 {       
                 while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT )              
                  {              
                              xpp_name=xpp.getName();                                   
                      if((xpp_name!=null) ) 
                                {
                                   --------------------
                                   -------------------------
                                }
                            }
                    }
               }
```

and

```
      public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
  try {  
       InputStream str=null;
       isInternetPresent=icd.isConnectingToInternet();
      if(isInternetPresent)
           {    
         str=url.openConnection().getInputStream(); 
         if(str!= null)
             {
             return str; 
          }else{
         new AlertDialogBox(getActivity()).show(getFragmentManager(),"MyDialog");
          }
    }else{
    new AlertDialogBox(getActivity()).show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
                            }
                                return    str;              
                            //}
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            return null;
                          }

                     }
```

Below is the erroe I am getting:
[image]

Comment: you should really log stuf when you catch exception. there is a good chance your inputstream is null.

Comment: It says unable to resolve host.

Comment: "njhgjghjkjhkjl" doesn't seem like a resolvable host, or a proper url.

Comment: I am not using that url, I have used that here only

Comment: Just checked using log this error is coming "java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing

```
 xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8"); to 
 xpp.setInput(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF_8");
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the NetworkOnMainThreadException. In that case to resolve it use AsyncTask to run code that accesses Network.

It causes because of accessing Network or Network related tasks on the main UI thread. This might sometimes hang or crash your app; freezes your app for some time. That is why  you are recommended to use AsyncTask to resolve this issue.

How to use AysncTask, read from here it is very easy:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Or you can add this line in your code that will allow Network accesses on main thread:

```
// Allow network thread to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException.

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Actually I am using Aync Task

Comment: Add this code in onCreate() method. - in the beginning is fine.

Comment: @ MasterJ: There is only one activity in my app and all other are fragments.In main activity I am declaring view pager.So do I need to add this code in the main Activity or in each fragment class?

Comment: OK Thank you, I will implement the code in the activity class.

Comment: I am implementing it in the code and after testing, I will accept.

Comment: Do not forget to accept it buddy? - As it is important for me and others to carry on this kinda conversations; for others this should clarify that this solutions works for the kinda problem you have gone through.